# How to supress/fix Susy 2.0 deprecated warnings

Tags: node-sass, susy

I am trying to suppress/fix a deprecated warning from my [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) (based on [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass)) compile that I traced to [Susy 2](http://oddbird.net/susy/) using functions listed to deprecate in Sass 4.0. At this point, it's not feasible to upgrade to Susy 3 as there's [no upgrade guide](https://github.com/oddbird/susy/issues/660) and will break a large website.

Node-sass offers a `--quiet` [option](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#command-line-interface) that I've passed in my `Gruntfile.js` though I am still getting the warning. This is my SASS section in my `Gruntfile.js`.

```
sass: {
    options: {
        quiet: true,
        sourceMap: false,
        outputStyle: 'compressed'
    },
    dist: {
        options: {
            quiet: true 
        },
       files: {
           'static/css/style.min.css' : 'static/css/sass/style.scss',
           'static/css/orderform.css' : 'static/css/sass/orderform.scss'
       }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to suppress deprecated warnings? Just ignoring the warnings will slow down my development, outputting all the warnings increases my compile time from ~1s to ~4s.

[Here is the log output](https://gist.github.com/jstnmthw/cb69f0029df4bd5e3c38bf16e377f07e)

Comment: What minor version of Susy 2 are you using? Version 2.2.14 was specifically released to solve this problem. If you are on 2.2.14 and still getting the warnings, can you paste them here or file an issue on github?

Comment: Hi @MiriamSuzanne, I am not sure what version it was but I switched to npm and installed Susy 2.2.14 then compiled from that but still getting deprecated warnings. I've edited my OP and added a Gist of the log output. Looks like only two functions are causing the warnings, `mixin-exists` and `variable-exists`.

Comment: That's very strange, because [we definitely use `get-function()` to capture functions](https://github.com/oddbird/susy/blob/susytwo/sass/susy/output/support/_support.scss#L73) in that release. I tried to reproduce this locally, but I'm not able to. I do get the warning when I write an improper `call()` - but I'm not able to get the same warning from Susy that you see. Are you sure the version of Susy being used is the version in npm?

Comment: You were absolutely correct, @MiriamSuzanne. I was compiling two SASS files one of which I forgot to correct the new Susy path. **No more deprecated warnings after upgrading to 2.2.14.** If you want to add the answer to this question I'll be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2.2.14 was specifically released to solve this problem. I tried to reproduce this locally in 2.2.14, but I'm not able to. I do get the warning when I write an improper `call()` - but I'm not able to get the same warning from Susy. Are you sure the version of Susy being used is the version in npm?

Comment: Thank you! This worked and I am no longer receiving warnings.